# Oracle SQL: Select Minimum and maximum from different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table which looks like this (max 2 rows per each Date-Item):

```
    Date        Item Price
    -----------------------
    20140101    A     100
    20140101    A     200
    20140101    B     50
    20140101    B     70
    20140102    A     20
    20140102    A     40
    20140102    B     10
    20140102    B     60
```

How can I have the maximum and minimum prices for each Date-Item pair in one row, as shown below?

There can be Date_Items with only one price (one row). For these pairs, I would like to have that price as Min_Price and NULL as Max_Price.

```
    Date        Item Min_Price  Max_Price
    --------------------------------------
    20140101    A     100      200
    20140101    B     50       70
    20140102    A     20       40
    20140102    B     10       60
```

Comment: this is rely easy. Try to learn aboub group by and min(), max(), functions

Comment: `SELECT date, item, MIN(price) min_price, MAX(price) max_price GROUP BY date, item`?

Comment: Well, I am a beginner. I tried something like: `select Date, Item, min(price), max(price) from myTable group by Date and Item`, and got this error message: "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Please read the syntax diagrams in the manual again. It's `group by Date, Item` (no `and` between the column names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT "Date", item, MIN(price) min_price, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(price) = MAX(price) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(price) END max_price
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY "Date", item
 ORDER BY "Date", item
```

or

```
SELECT "Date", item, MIN(price) min_price,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(price) END max_price
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY "Date", item
 ORDER BY "Date", item
```

depending on how you want to treat the scenario when on the same day you have two rows with the same price if it is at all possible.

Output:

```
|                           DATE | ITEM | MIN_PRICE | MAX_PRICE |
|--------------------------------|------|-----------|-----------|
| January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    A |       100 |       200 |
| January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    B |        50 |        70 |
| January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    A |        20 |        40 |
| January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    B |        10 |        60 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d87ef/5)** demo

Comment: @user1777530 You're quite welcome! I'm glad it helped ;) Good luck.

Comment: @user1777530 Someone down voted my answer without leaving a comment. That's why I asked.

Comment: What if for a particular day both entries are there with the same value?
P.S - I am not the one who voted down

Comment: @San It's up to OP to decide according to actual requirements, but IMHO it can be treated as like there were no second row.

Comment: How about using below code?
select dt, item, decode(count(1), 2, max(price), null) MAX_P, Min(price) MIN_P
from table_name
group by dt, item;

Comment: @San Good thinking. It's a possibility too. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The key to such queries is a `GROUP BY` clause. When you use such a clause, you produce a single row per unique value of the column(s) you're grouping by. This means that the select list for your query may only contain expressions which have a single value per such group - either items from the select list itself or aggregate functions.

Once you get this prinicipal, having a `null` value for a `date`-`item` combination with a single entry could be acheiced with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT date, item, 
       min_price,
       CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN max_price ELSE NULL END AS max_price
FROM   (SELECT   date, item, 
                 COUNT(*) AS cnt, MIN(price) AS min_price, MAX(price) AS max_price
        FROM     mytable
        GROUP BY date, item) t
```